# using partition by clause in delete statement postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete

I am trying to debug the below code. It throws me an error saying  ERROR: syntax error at or near "(" .

My aim to to delete duplicate records in the table

```
 delete FROM (SELECT *,
                         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition BY snapshot,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5) AS rnum
                 FROM table where snapshot='2019-08-31')  as t
          WHERE t.rnum > 1;
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres does not allow deleting from subqueries.  You can `join` in other tables.  But in this case, I think a correlated subquery is sufficient, assuming you have a unique id of some sort:

```
delete from t
    where snapshot = '2019-08-31' and
          id > (select min(id)
                from t t2
                where t2.snapshot = t.snapshot and
                      t2.col1 = t.col1 and
                      t2.col2 = t.col2 and
                      t2.col3 = t.col3 and
                      t2.col4 = t.col4 and
                      t2.col5 = t.col5
               );
```

Note:  This also assumes that the columns are not `NULL`.  You can replace `=` with `is not distinct from` if `NULL`s are a possibility.

If you have lots of duplicates and no identity column, you might find it simpler to remove and re-insert the data:

```
create table temp_snapshot as
    select distinct on (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5) t.*
    from t
    where snapshot = '2019-08-31'
    order by col1, col2, col3, col4, col5;

delete from t
    where col1, col2, col3, col4, col5;

insert into t
    select *
    from temp_snapshot;
```

If your table is partitioned by `snapshot` (possibly a very good idea), then you can drop the partition instead and then add the data back in.  That process is typically faster than deleting records.

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
DELETE FROM table a
WHERE a.ctid <> (SELECT min(b.ctid)
                 FROM   table b
                 WHERE  a.snapshot = b.snapshot
                          and a.col1=b.col1 and a.col2=b.col2);
```